# rsync with --link-dest options doesn't create hard links

Tags: rsync, backup

I created a backup script that should create incremental backups every day and a full backup once a week from a remote host to my external backup hard drive.

(short example at the bottom)

The script (https://gist.github.com/sergei-maertens/ac6b8ee2562edcff10fc):

```
#!/bin/env bash

#
# Adapted from http://webgnuru.com/linux/rsync_incremental.php
#

USER='modelbrouw'
HOST='modelbrouwers.nl'
DAYS_BETWEEN_FULL=30  # number of days between full backups.

TARGET_SUFFIX="media"
TARGET_BASE="/run/media/bbt/40d67de8-f4b6-4707-9947-f96f44efd7bf/"
SOURCE="/home/modelbrouw/django/production/$TARGET_SUFFIX"


today=`date -I`
prev_day=$today  # check if backup from today exists


get_target() {
    root_dir=$TARGET_BASE$1
    if [[ $2 ]]; then
        root_dir=$root_dir/$2
    fi
    echo $root_dir
}


LOG=`get_target $today 'rsync_inc.log'`

# do the date calculations
# determine if a full/incremental backup should be taken
run_backup() {
    i=0
    PREV_BACKUP=`get_target $prev_day`

    while [ $i -lt 100 ] && [ ! -d $PREV_BACKUP ]
    do
        i=$[i+1]
        prev_day=`date -I -d "$i day ago"`
        PREV_BACKUP=`get_target $prev_day`
    done

    if [ $i -eq '0' ]; then
        echo "Backup already created"
        # exit
    else
        echo $i 'days since last backup'
    fi

    # create the target directory
    TARGET=`get_target $today`
    echo -e 'Backup target:' $TARGET "\n"
    mkdir -p $TARGET

    if [ $i -lt $DAYS_BETWEEN_FULL ]; then
        echo -e "creating incremental backup, based on" $prev_day "\n"
        incremental_backup
    else
        echo -e "creating full backup \n"
        source ./backup.sh
    fi
}


incremental_backup() {
    DEST=`get_target $today $TARGET_SUFFIX`
    COMP=`get_target $prev_day $TARGET_SUFFIX`
    echo 'remote source directory:' $SOURCE
    echo 'backup destination:' $DEST

    SSH="-e ssh $USER@$HOST:$SOURCE"
    OPT="-rvLtShP"

    echo $LOG
    rsync $OPT --link-dest=$COMP $SSH $TARGET > $LOG
}

run_backup
```

**What it's supposed to do**
Basically what it does it create a target folder for the backup with today's date, look for the previous backup (subtract one day from the previous date until a folder was found, since I cannot run the backup every day/night) and if more than 7 days elapsed, a full backup will be created.

This backup is quite large, so I want to use --link-dest to create hard links to the previous backup if the file hasn't changed.

The remote host is accessed with passwordless ssh, nothing special going on here.

**What it does**

The observed behaviour is that the backup is indeed created correctly, but no hard links are created, even though files appear to be identical.

**Potential useful information**

Some more possibly related information:

- the remote host filesystem is simfs, OS is CentOS 5.11
- the backup drive filesystem is ext4, running from Arch Linux machine
- file mtimes match (if I interpret the stat output correctly)
- both machines are in the same timezone
- local machine rsync version 3.1.1
- remote machine rsync version 3.0.6

**What else did I try**

I ran rsync with the same options and via ssh on my local machine with the folders /home/bbt/test/source, /home/bbt/test/prev, /home/bbt/test/target. The `target` folder files do indeed have hard links to the `prev` folder files, as expected.

**Output from currently running backup**

```
➜  scripts  ./run_backup.sh
2 days since last backup
Backup target: /run/media/bbt/40d67de8-f4b6-4707-9947-f96f44efd7bf/2015-10-24 

creating incremental backup, based on 2015-10-22 

remote source directory: /home/modelbrouw/django/production/media
backup destination: /run/media/bbt/40d67de8-f4b6-4707-9947-f96f44efd7bf/2015-10-24/media
```

Then I went to verify a test file:

```
    ➜  1  pwd
/run/media/bbt/40d67de8-f4b6-4707-9947-f96f44efd7bf/2015-10-22/media/albums/1/1
➜  1  stat 1024_chameleon.jpg 
  File: ‘1024_chameleon.jpg’
  Size: 31694       Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 81264905    Links: 1
Access: (0645/-rw-r--r-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     bbt)   Gid: ( 1000/     bbt)
Access: 2015-10-22 20:32:09.550197848 +0200
Modify: 2012-07-04 19:13:10.000000000 +0200
Change: 2015-10-22 20:32:09.550197848 +0200
 Birth: -
```

And check the corresponding file in the new backup - here I would expect a hard link:

```
➜  1  pwd
/run/media/bbt/40d67de8-f4b6-4707-9947-f96f44efd7bf/2015-10-24/media/albums/1/1
➜  1  stat 1024_chameleon.jpg 
  File: ‘1024_chameleon.jpg’
  Size: 31694       Blocks: 64         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 107348180   Links: 1
Access: (0645/-rw-r--r-x)  Uid: ( 1000/     bbt)   Gid: ( 1000/     bbt)
Access: 2015-10-24 17:07:01.695760211 +0200
Modify: 2012-07-04 19:13:10.000000000 +0200
Change: 2015-10-24 17:00:34.284219203 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Finally, I log all rsync output as well, the head of the file looks like this:

```
➜  2015-10-24  head rsync_inc.log -n 100
receiving incremental file list
media/
media/.htaccess
             49 100%   47.85kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, ir-chk=1114/1116)
media/albums/
media/albums/1/
media/albums/1/1/
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0551.jpg
         74.35K 100%   77.74kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, ir-chk=1276/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0552.jpg
         81.28K 100%   82.26kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, ir-chk=1275/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0553.jpg
         59.76K 100%   59.68kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#4, ir-chk=1274/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0554.jpg
        100.46K 100%   97.32kB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#5, ir-chk=1273/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0555.jpg
        105.82K 100%    3.15MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#6, ir-chk=1272/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_Foto0556.jpg
         82.08K 100%    1.53MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#7, ir-chk=1271/2436)
media/albums/1/1/1024_chameleon.jpg
         31.69K 100%  562.75kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#8, ir-chk=1270/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0551.jpg
         49.58K 100%  691.70kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#9, ir-chk=1269/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0552.jpg
         55.32K 100%  675.32kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#10, ir-chk=1268/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0553.jpg
         41.20K 100%  410.56kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#11, ir-chk=1267/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0554.jpg
         67.87K 100%  597.15kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#12, ir-chk=1266/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0555.jpg
         69.35K 100%  559.73kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#13, ir-chk=1265/2436)
media/albums/1/1/Foto0556.jpg
         56.50K 100%  396.95kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#14, ir-chk=1264/2436)
media/albums/1/1/chameleon.jpg
         20.77K 100%  145.92kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#15, ir-chk=1263/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0551.jpg
          2.41K 100%   16.82kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#16, ir-chk=1262/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0552.jpg
          2.57K 100%   17.95kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#17, ir-chk=1261/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0553.jpg
          2.37K 100%   16.50kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#18, ir-chk=1260/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0554.jpg
          3.21K 100%   21.33kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#19, ir-chk=1259/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0555.jpg
          2.94K 100%   19.56kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#20, ir-chk=1258/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_Foto0556.jpg
          2.91K 100%   19.31kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#21, ir-chk=1257/2436)
media/albums/1/1/thumb_chameleon.jpg
          1.45K 100%    9.60kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#22, ir-chk=1256/2436)
media/albums/1/14/
media/albums/1/14/2012-07-28 20.46.38.jpg
         89.52K 100%  526.65kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#23, ir-chk=1255/2436)
media/albums/1/14/2012-07-28 20.46.50.jpg
         99.56K 100%  522.70kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#24, ir-chk=1254/2436)
media/albums/1/14/2012-07-28 20.47.49.jpg
        121.80K 100%  553.25kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#25, ir-chk=1253/2436)
media/albums/1/14/2012-07-28 20.47.59.jpg
        117.66K 100%  476.78kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#26, ir-chk=1252/2436)
media/albums/1/14/2012-07-28 20.48.06.jpg
        101.82K 100%  380.98kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#27, ir-chk=1251/2436)
media/albums/1/14/thumb_2012-07-28 20.46.38.jpg
          6.99K 100%   26.16kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#28, ir-chk=1250/2436)
media/albums/1/14/thumb_2012-07-28 20.46.50.jpg
          7.55K 100%   28.25kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#29, ir-chk=1249/2436)
media/albums/1/14/thumb_2012-07-28 20.47.49.jpg
          7.13K 100%   25.98kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#30, ir-chk=1248/2436)
media/albums/1/14/thumb_2012-07-28 20.47.59.jpg
          6.81K 100%   24.82kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#31, ir-chk=1247/2436)
media/albums/1/14/thumb_2012-07-28 20.48.06.jpg
          7.33K 100%   26.72kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#32, ir-chk=1246/2436)
media/albums/1/2/
media/albums/1/2/1024_2012-05-03 21.49.27.jpg
         56.56K 100%  197.97kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#33, ir-chk=1245/2436)
media/albums/1/2/1024_2012-05-03 22.37.00.jpg
         53.89K 100%  167.60kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#34, ir-chk=1244/2436)
media/albums/1/2/2012-05-03 21.49.27.jpg
         56.56K 100%  173.15kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#35, ir-chk=1243/2436)
media/albums/1/2/2012-05-03 22.37.00.jpg
         53.89K 100%  158.99kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#36, ir-chk=1242/2436)
media/albums/1/2/2012-05-03 22.53.39.jpg
         60.56K 100%  169.46kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#37, ir-chk=1241/2436)
media/albums/1/2/thumb_2012-05-03 21.49.27.jpg
          2.44K 100%    6.80kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#38, ir-chk=1240/2436)
media/albums/1/2/thumb_2012-05-03 22.37.00.jpg
          2.55K 100%    7.10kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#39, ir-chk=1239/2436)
media/albums/1/2/thumb_2012-05-03 22.53.39.jpg
          2.62K 100%    7.31kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#40, ir-chk=1238/2436)
media/albums/1/23/
media/albums/1/23/2012-08-09-224554_1366x768_scrot.png
        152.05K 100%  370.28kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#41, ir-chk=1237/2436)
media/albums/1/23/2012-08-29-170808_1366x768_scrot.png
        162.87K 100%  363.13kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#42, ir-chk=1236/2436)
media/albums/1/23/2012-09-02-014215_1366x768_scrot.png
        155.44K 100%  316.91kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#43, ir-chk=1235/2436)
media/albums/1/23/2012-09-02-131516_1366x768_scrot.png
        147.72K 100%  275.30kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#44, ir-chk=1234/2436)
media/albums/1/23/2012-09-02-131523_1366x768_scrot.png
        259.65K 100%  417.74kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#45, ir-chk=1233/2436)
media/albums/1/23/2012-09-08-231233_1366x768_scrot.png
        171.33K 100%  260.20kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#46, ir-chk=1232/2436)
```

The full log file from the previous backup (which ran with the same script) can be found at https://modelbrouwers.nl/static/rsync_inc.log

**Short example**

the command that gets run:

```
rsync -rvLtShP --link-dest=/backupdrive/2015-10-22/media -e ssh modelbrouw@modelbrouwers.nl:/home/modelbrouw/django/production/media /backupdrive/2015-10-24
```

In the backup target (2015-10-24) I would expect a hard link from `/backupdrive/2015-10-24/media/albums/1/1/1024_chameleon.jpg` to `/backupdrive/2015-10-21/media/albums/1/1/1024_chameleon.jpg`

... and as I'm writing this, I probably have to add the `media` to the target. I'll try that out first now.

Comment: Hello BBT and welcome to Unix.SE. Instead of dumping the entire script, can you provide a _short_ example illustrating the problem you're describing, please.

Comment: thank you roaima

I have edited the question and added a short example at the bottom. I also realize I might have found the issue, so I'll try that first.

Comment: Glad you found the problem. As a suggestion, I would recommend doing the rsync initially to a directory like `2015-10-24.tmp` and then renaming it to `2015-10-24` at the end if the rsync exits with code 0.  Otherwise, in case of error the previous day, you may  have a directory that is only partially filled that will be used as the new link-dest, so you will be using up real file space again. Note there is also an `rsnapshot` command, though I've not used it.

Comment: That's a very good suggestion, thanks.

I've heard of rsnapshot - we use it at work, but haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: BTW, I don't recall ever seeing a system that had bash, where it wasn't available as `/bin/bash`, but I've definitely seen systems that have env, where it isn't available as `/bin/env`.  The standard location for `env` is `/usr/bin/env`, so if you're going to use it in your she-bang line (or reference it by full path for any other reason), you should use that.  But `#!/bin/bash` is probably safe.

Comment: Ah yes, I've juggled those ones. Should ofcourse just be `/usr/bin/env`.

Answer (score 1):

The trailing slash + missing part of path bit me, typing out the short example helped.

The solution is that the trailing slash must be added to the `$SOURCE` and `media` needs to be added to the eventual `$TARGET`.